# Is there a more elegant (less code) way of getting JSON into a DataTable (C#)

Tags: c#, json, rest, etl

Recently I ended up with a project to do Extract Transform and Load with the data sources being Salesforce, GitHub, ReviewBoard, Jenkins, etc. In other words a stack of REST/JSON interfaces. The classic way of deserializing to classes looked like it would both be time consuming, create a huge code base, etc. So I spent a little time looking for alternatives.

Below is what I came up with -- Rest Call to .Net DataSet in a few lines. Moving from a .Net Dataset to a Data Mart or Data Warehouse is low effort.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Avalara.AvaTax.JsonUtilities
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static DataSet GetDataSet(string url, string rootName = "myroot")
        {
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json, *.*";
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", Authorization);
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", webResponse.Headers);
            var json = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
            // We must name the root element
            return ConvertJsonToDataSet(json, rootName);
        }
        public static DataSet ConvertJsonToDataSet(string jsonText, string rootElementName)
        {
            var xd1 = new XmlDocument();
            xd1 =JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode( jsonText,rootElementName);
            var result = new DataSet();
            result.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd1));
            return result;
        }  
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing ETL from Json to DataSet?

Comment: Most of that is the web-request part, the JSON part is pretty small already...

Comment: If I was going to make that more elegant I'd add extension methods for WebRequest (GetResponseJson(url)) that encapsulated the parameters. Then an extension method for DataSet (ReadJsonStream(Stream)). At the end of the day the same code is being executed but your client is reduced to 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: This seems more like a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) type of question.

Comment: Json.NET already has built-in support for deserializing a `DataSet`, see [Deserialize a DataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm).  What does your JSON look like?  Does it match the format expected by Json.NET?